# Defer Javascript to optimize website

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, performance, pagespeed

I am **optimizing my website** and I am using Google Analytics tool to check the score.

I referred to many articles and researched on stackoverflow.com also, but not getting any proper solution.

My issue is I have placed all the .js files at the end of page near closing body tag, but analysis says **Defer Javascript** and gives a list of js files.

**Code in aspx file is as shown below:**

```
<body>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/default.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35073844-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

    </script>

</body>
```

I also tried the **defer attribute** but there is no change in score.

I also tried the javascript **code** as shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 // Add a script element as a child of the body
 function downloadJSAtOnload() {
 var element = document.createElement("script");
 element.src = "js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js";
 document.body.appendChild(element);
 }

 // Check for browser support of event handling capability
 if (window.addEventListener)
 window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
 else if (window.attachEvent)
 window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
 else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;

</script>
```

But still no change.

Can I get some links about deferring javascript to understand it thoroughly?

I am not much experienced in javascript.

Please help. Thank You.

Comment: Why do you need to optimize the site, do the scripts load too slowly?

Comment: [Here's a document on javascript parsing deferring](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/payload#DeferParsingJS). Personally I found it to be one of the most difficult goals of [pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/).

Comment: The analysis tools are make mistakes in many difficult code. Also because is say make the code defer is not mean that you been able to do that and run your site.

Comment: @dystroy-I have already referred to this document but could not find any solution. No matter what I do to defer javascript my score remains unchanged. Any other way round?

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention which browser you tested with as historically not all browsers supported defer but support is much better now (http://caniuse.com/script-defer)

Aarron Peters wrote a good post on defering JS until onload fired http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/why-loading-third-party-scripts-async-is-not-good-enough

His code basically looks like:

```
<script>
(function(w, d, s) {
  function go(){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0], load = function(url, id) {
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement(s); js.src = url; js.id = id;
       fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    };
    load('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=272697932759946&xfbml=1', 'fbjssdk');
    load('https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js', 'gplus1js');
    load('//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', 'tweetjs');
  }
  if (w.addEventListener) { w.addEventListener("load", go, false); }
  else if (w.attachEvent) { w.attachEvent("onload",go); }
}(window, document, 'script'));
</script>
```

Personally I'd prefer a way of declaratively specifying the point that the element is deferred to e.g. `defer="onload"` but that comes with some issues.

Comment: I am testing on browsers chrome, mozilla and IE.

Comment: and I have many more js files, should I include all of them in this code like you showed plusone.js and widgets.js??

Comment: You should reduce the number of JS resources by merging some of them together. How many you defer to onload depends on how you page is constructed. I'd put the code at the bottom of the page but again is depends.